# Does the next integral $\int_0^{\pi\over 2}{ x \sin(\tan x)\over \cos x}dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus

Does the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi\over 2}{ x \sin(\tan(x))\over \cos x}dx$ converge? I found it diffcult to solve. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: What is $tgx$? ${}$

Comment: tanx. Fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is as
$x \to \pi/2$,
so let's look at
$\int_{{\pi\over 2}-c}^{\pi\over 2}{ x \sin(\tan(x))\over \cos x}dx$
and see what happens for small $c$.
(I use $c$ instead of $\epsilon$ because is takes fewer characters to type.)

Replacing $x$ by $\pi/2-x$,
this becomes
$\int_0^c{ (\pi/2-x) \sin(\tan(\pi/2-x))\over \cos (\pi/2-x)}dx
=\int_0^c{ (\pi/2-x) \sin(1/\tan(x))\over \sin (x)}dx
$.

For small $x$,
$\sin(x) \text{ and }\tan(x) \approx x$
and $\pi/2-x \approx \pi/2$,
so this becomes
$\int_0^c{ (\pi/2) \sin(1/x)\over x}dx
\approx (\pi/2)\int_0^c  \frac{\sin(1/x)}{x} dx
$.

Let $y=1/x$, so $dx=-dy/y^2$.
The integral becomes
$\int_{1/c}^{\infty} \frac{y\sin(y)}{y^2} dy
=\int_{1/c}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(y)}{y} dy
$.

This can be proven to converge in a number of ways.
Here are two:

1. Divide the region into intervals
   where $\sin(x)$ is of constant sign,
   show that the absolute values of the integral
   over each interval decreases,
   and use the alternating series theorem.
2. Integrate by parts to get
   $ -\cos(y)/y - \int(\cos(y)/y^2)dy$
   and since the first part converges
   and the second part is dominated by
   $\int_{1/c}^{\infty} 1/y^2 dy
   = -\frac1{y}\big|_{1/c}^{\infty}
   =c
   $,
   it converges.

Comment: In the 3rd line when you replace $x$ by $\pi/2-x$ you neglected to change the $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: @marty Can you explain the boundries in the second line? How did they become from 0 to c? Thanks!

Comment: For $x$ from $0$ to $\pi/2-c$, the function behaves nicely and will not affect convergence. It is only when $x$ gets close to $\pi/2$ that things get interesting.

Comment: To vadim123: I think I am correct. I replaced $\tan(\pi/2-x)$ by $1/\tan(x)$. Is that what you were writing about?